# Is there an inplace map function for mutable vectors?

Tags: haskell, vector

If I have a mutable vector (with type `IOVector a` for example), is there a map-like function that can modify the elements in place?

The `vector` package provides the `modify` function but this is only one element at a time. Should I use this or is there a preferred method?

And to clarify, the type of the vector will be the same before and after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, use `modify` if you want to modify elements in place. If you find yourself often modifying everything in place, you can define `mapModify` as follows.

```
import Data.Foldable (for_)
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as MV

mapModify :: (a -> a) -> IOVector a -> IO ()
mapModify f v = for_ [0 .. MV.length v - 1)] (MV.modify v f)
```

That said, constantly modifying all elements in a vector sounds like you may be better off using immutable vectors and mapping over them using the regular `fmap`. If that code ends up fusing properly, the intermediate vectors will never even be materialized.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to use fusion but it sounds like using immutable vectors might be the best thing to use.

Comment: @user668074, one reason you may not want to actually modify all the elements like this is that laziness could kill your efficiency. A `mapModify'` that forces each result before installing it would probably be more useful. If the lazy pure version fuses with some other operation, it could also be okay.